# Firebase hosting test hosting configuration settings

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am looking for a method to test the current provided hosting configuration for Firebase Hosting, the `firebase.json` file seems to deploy correctly, but there doesn't seem to be a way to see this configuration on the cloud once its deployed:

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/v1/**",
        "function": "webApp"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**/*",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache"
          },
          {
            "key": "Content-Security-Policy",
            "value": "frame-ancestors 'self' *://*.hellosign.com"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 8080
    },
    "database": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 9000
    },
    "hosting": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 5000
    },
    "pubsub": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 8085
    },
    "auth": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 9099
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true,
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 4000
    }
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#where-to-define-config) states:

> You can check the deployed firebase.json content using the [Hosting REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/hosting/rest/v1beta1/sites.releases/list?apix_params=%7B%22parent%22%3A%22sites%2F%3Cyour-site-name%3E%22%2C%22pageSize%22%3A1%7D).

You will need to use that API to check that your release matches your expectations.  You won't be able to see this in the console.  If console access what you're looking for, then file a feature request with [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).